# Parsing one PDO string containing multiple images into multiple img elements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently querying my SQL table using PDO to echo out some data.

Everything was going fine until I noticed that the MySQL table I am parsing included an image column that contains 7 images separated by commas.

Here is an example of the string that the column contains:

```
http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_1b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_2b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_3b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_4b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_5b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_6b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_7b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_8b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_9b.jpg
```

I am currently echoing my results onto the front end with the following code:

```
<?php while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
      echo '<div>'.$row["FirstColumn"].'</div>';
} ?>
```

So how could I insert each image link within the string into separate img elements?

I take it the comma will be the key however I am a little confused how I can make this happen.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Read up on PHP `explode()` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string into individual image paths and then iterate through the list with [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$images = 'http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_1b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_2b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_3b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_4b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_5b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_6b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_7b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_8b.jpg,http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV85190781_9b.jpg';

foreach(explode(',', $images) as $image) {
  echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
}
```

I would also consider normalizing the database table using a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```php
while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $images = explode(',', $row['FirstColumn']); // Split the string 

    echo '<div>';

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    echo '<div>' . 
    implode('</div><div>', explode(',', $row["FirstColumn"])) .
    '</div>';
}
```